# How to change range in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array (A) like this:

```
[-2.27673806e+76 -1.822e0106e+76 -1.48021731e+75 -4.18273604e+76
 -6.42808765e+75 -4.93893422e+76 -1.08387039e+77 -3.44601768e+75
 -2.43643739e+76 -1.34004939e+76 -8.55241963e+75 -2.04812001e+74
 -4.17638084e+76 -7.58142011e+75 ...]
```

Now I want to multiply all the values within the array, but since they are super small, i will have an overflow. I was thinking to shift the range by the np.min() decimal place. How can I do that?

As per request in comments:

```
np.prod(A)
> inf

min = np.log10(-np.min(A))
B = A*(10**(-min-1))

#B*10**(sum(log10 of all As))
```

Comment: One thing you can do is to do it in the log domain. Negative numbers will make it trickier though...

Comment: Please let us know if you have done any trials. Also information is not clear about expected output.

Comment: @OO7 I updated what I currently try. But I don't know if it works.

Comment: Change the range? What does this mean? Do you want to normalize your data on a [a, b] interval?

Comment: @Mathieu don't know how to explain. What I actually want is to multiply them all, so I will have a result instead of `inf`. So I was thinking to change the decimal places domain. Sorry. I don't know the correct term about what I want to do here. That's why I ask for help.

Comment: Ok but what is the point? Imagine you divide everything by your smaller 10th power, in the example e74. Then you multiply your 'rescaled' array by whatever and then what? You can't go back to the original result by multiplying by e74, you will end up with inf again. So what is the point?

Comment: @Mathieu True. Actually I have a formula which I want to make numerically stabil. So what I address here shows me that this can not be part of the solution... Thanks for your help!